# Android ListView select number of items to display leads to shuffling items

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView where I show dates. By using a Spinner, I can choose how many days I want to display (if the list is too long, then I can scroll through it).

[image]

When I'm seeing 30 days, and am at the bottom of the list, if I play with the spinner and choose to see 15 days, then 30 days, then 15 days, I end up with duplicated or wrong elements.

[image]

I've read many things about that, applied every suggestion:

- invalidate
- invalidateViews
- notifyDataSetInvalidated
- notifyDataSetChanged
- refreshDrawableState
- use Handler to run those calls

but nothing fixed my problem.

I'm using the following code:

=== CustomAdapter ===

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<ViewHolder> viewHolders;

    @Inject
    public CustomAdapter(@Assisted List<ViewHolder> viewHolders) {
        this.viewHolders = viewHolders;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return viewHolders.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return viewHolders.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return viewHolders.get(i).getView(view);
    }
}
```

=== ListViewHolder ===

```
public class ListViewHolder extends ViewHolder {

    @Override
    public View getView(View view) {
        Holder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(contextProvider.get()).inflate(R.layout.entry, null);
            holder = new Holder();

            holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            view.setTag(viewStructure);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(/* date */);

        return view;
    }
}
```

=== ListFragment ===

```
public class ListFragment extends RoboFragment {

    private CustomAdapter customAdapter = null;

    private List<ViewHolder> viewHolders = new ArrayList<ViewHolder>();

    private ListView listView;

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Inject
    private ListFragment(AdapterFactory adapterFactory) {
        customAdapter = adapterFactory.createAdapter(viewHolders);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    public void setContentRange(List<ViewHolder> viewHolders, int range) {
        update(viewHolders.subList(0, range));
    }

    private void update(List<ViewHolder> content) {
        viewHolders.clear();
        viewHolders.addAll(content);

        if (customAdapter != null) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //customAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

                    if (listView != null) {
                        listView.invalidateViews();
                    //    listView.requestLayout();
                    //    listView.refreshDrawableState();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Sorry, can't post pictures, not enough reputation...

EDIT:

- added link for pictures
- The code for the ListViewHolder is actually like this. I simplified it to post here, but maybe it matters:

  public class ListViewHolder extends ViewHolder {

  ```
  @Inject
  private ListViewHolder(Holder holder) { // Guice will create the holder
      super(holder);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(View view) {
      Holder holder;

      if (view == null) {
          view = LayoutInflater.from(contextProvider.get()).inflate(R.layout.entry, null);
          holder = getHolder(); // getHolder is defined in ViewHolder, and returns the object created in the constructor

          holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

          view.setTag(viewStructure);
      } else {
          holder = (DualTextViewStructure) view.getTag();
      }

      holder.text.setText(/* Date */);

      return view;
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: "Sorry, can't post pictures, not enough reputation" -- upload elsewhere, then link to them from your question.

Comment: Try to add logs. Print your list every time you change items in adapter (maybe something going wrong with items list). Add log in method getView() in Adapter and ViewHolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that using the Holder created by Guice in the constructor was the problem.
If I use a Provider, then the list behaves as expected

```
public class ListViewHolder extends ViewHolder {

    @Override
    public View getView(View view) {
        Holder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(contextProvider.get()).inflate(R.layout.entry, null);
            // getHolder looks like this:
            // @Inject
            // private Provider<Holder> holderProvider;
            // public Holder getHolder() {
            //     holderProvider.get();
            // }
            holder = getHolder();

            holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            view.setTag(viewStructure);
        } else {
            holder = (DualTextViewStructure) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(/* Date */);

        return view;
    }
}
```